# remove element from json file using jq

Tags: json, jq

Maybe you could give me a right direction using this 'jq' component, I was using 'yq' and now I have to change to 'jq', so I wanted to convert to equivalent but I couldn't

```
yq -i 'del(.body.*.error)' "output.json"
```

The idea is to delete 'error' field in every child, without specifying every field, only one general character, similar than equivalent in above yq.

```
delpaths([["body",".$","error"]])
```

but this is not working, this is my json file:

```
{
    "body": {
        "field1":{
            "name": "test",
            "error":"messsage empty"
        },
        "field2":{
            "name":"jose"
        },
        "field3":{
            "name":"tere",
            "error":"messsage empty 2"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my expectation:

```
{
    "body": {
        "field1":{
            "name": "test",
        },
        "field2":{
            "name":"jose"
        },
        "field3":{
            "name":"tere",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your full JSON? It it important that only errors nested in `body` are deleted? Are errors always direct children of `fieldX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delete 'error' field in every child

One way to delete every "error" field in every object:

```
jq 'del(..|objects|.error)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try indexing with `[]` instead.

```
del(.body[].error)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uxpewQc0i7P)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This removes `error` properties anywhere in your document:

```
del(..|.error?)
```

Might be sufficient, might be not, depending on the real structure of your document.

Comment: yeah it is working but is removing from whole document that tag, I am using this del(.body[].error), thanks for your help